# I want to right click and open link in new tab using selenium with python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

action = ActionChains(driver)

action.context_click(driver.find_element_by_id('id')).perform()
```

it's doing a right click for me but unable to perform further action.like open link in new tab using python

Comment: could you please share the html.

Comment: It can be any url take the example of facebook.com right click on that link and open the link in new tab

Answer (score 3):

First off, we import our packages:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
```

Let's do it:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.google.com?q=python#q=python')
first_result = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(lambda browser: browser.find_element_by_class_name('rc'))
first_link = first_result.find_element_by_tag_name('a')

# Save the window opener (current window, do not mistaken with tab... not the same)
main_window = browser.current_window_handle

# Open the link in a new tab by sending key strokes on the element
# Use: Keys.CONTROL + Keys.SHIFT + Keys.RETURN to open tab on top of the stack 
first_link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)

# Switch tab to the new tab, which we will assume is the next one on the right
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)

# Put focus on current window which will, in fact, put focus on the current visible tab
browser.switch_to_window(main_window)

# do whatever you have to do on this page, we will just got to sleep for now
sleep(2)

# Close current tab
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')

# Put focus on current window which will be the window opener
browser.switch_to_window(main_window)
```

Comment: Thank your posting this! This is the ONLY solution that has ever worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

As discussed with you.I have tried to open a create page on Facebook as a new window using right click options.Here is the code.Hope this help you.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/Java/TestChrome/lib/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()[contains(.,'Create a Page')]]")
#Open in new window to click on Create page using right click
ActionChains(driver).context_click(element).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(element).perform()
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I need to do it by using right click and then open the link

Comment: Ok let me check.

Comment: Yes i do it's doing right click and then again hit the link with same selector.is there any way it open the link using the pop up appears after the right click

Comment: [http://www.testingbar.com/how-to-perform-context-clickright-click-action-in-selenium-webdriver/]
please have a look at this link i wnat to perform that using python